# Sorted a javascript array of objects by an object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

Hay, i have an array of objects and i need to sort them (either DESC or ASC) by a certain property of each object.

Here's the data

```
obj1 = new Object;
obj1.date = 1307010000;

obj2 = new Object;
obj2.date = 1306923600;

obj3 = new Object;
obj3.date = 1298974800;

obj4 = new Object;
obj4.date = 1306923600;

obj5 = new Object;
obj5.date = 1307096400;

data = [obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4,obj5];
```

Now, i want to order the data array so that the objects are in order by date.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use the Array [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method

```
data.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.date - b.date;
});
```

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
data.sort(function(a,b){
   return a.date - b.date; //to reverse b.date-a.date
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution works with any type of data:

```
sort_array_by = function(field, reverse, pr){
  reverse = (reverse) ? -1 : 1;
  return function(a,b){
    a = a[field];
    b = b[field];
    if (typeof(pr) != 'undefined'){
      a = pr(a);
      b = pr(b);
    }
    if (a<b) return reverse * -1;
    if (a>b) return reverse * 1;
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Then, use it like this (reverse sort):

```
data.sort(sort_array_by('date', true, function(a){
   return new Date(a);
}));
```

As another example, you can sort it by a property of type "integer":

```
data.sort(sort_array_by('my_int_property', true, function(a){
   return parseInt(a);
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

We have an application using Angular/TypeScript and found it slightly easier on the eyes using an arrow function. In our case, the following code is example of what we have:

```
data.sort((a, b) => a.SortOrder - b.SortOrder);
```

Not a huge change but this helps moreso when you have many objects to be sorted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom sort function:

```
function mySort(a,b) {
    return (a.date - b.date);
}
data.sort(mySort);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how i use sorting array of objects in ascending order here "array" is array of an object.copy paste in a script tag and understand working through console...

```
function OBJECT(){
    this.PROPERTY1 =Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1) ;


}

OBJECT.prototype.getPROPERTY1=function (){
    return(this.PROPERTY1);
}
OBJECT.prototype.setPROPERTY1=function (PROPERTY){
    this.PROPERTY1=PROPERTY;
}

var array= new Array();
console.log("unsorted object")
for(var a=0;a<10;a++)
{
array.push(new OBJECT());
console.log(array[a].getPROPERTY1())
}


function sorting() {
    for(var i in array){
        array[i].setPROPERTY1((array[i].getPROPERTY1()*1))
             //that is just for sorting an integer value escape this line if not an                                      
            //integer property
    }

    var arr=new(Array);
    var temp1=new(Array);
    for(var i in array){
        temp1.push(array[i]);
    }
     var temporary=new(Array)
    for(var i in array)
    {
        var temp = array[i].getPROPERTY1();
        arr.push(temp);
    }
    arr.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
    //the argument above is very important

    console.log(arr)
    for(var i in arr){

        for(var j in temp1)
            if(arr[i]==temp1[j].getPROPERTY1())
                break;

        temporary.push(temp1[j])


        temp1.splice(j,1)//just this statement works for me

    }
    array.length=0;
    for(var i in temporary)
    {
        array.push(temporary[i])
    }



}


     sorting();
      console.log("sorted object")
 for(var a=0;a<10;a++)
 {
             console.log(array[a].getPROPERTY1())
 }
```