# array of object data sort not working

Tags: javascript

​

```
0: Object { gradeName: "A+", gradeMaxMarks: "89", gradeMinMarks: "80" }
​
1: Object { gradeName: "A", gradeMaxMarks: "79", gradeMinMarks: "70" }
​
2: Object { gradeName: "B+", gradeMaxMarks: "69", gradeMinMarks: "60" }
​
3: Object { gradeName: "B", gradeMaxMarks: "59", gradeMinMarks: "55" }
​
4: Object { gradeName: "C", gradeMaxMarks: "49", gradeMinMarks: "40" }
​
5: Object { gradeName: "D", gradeMaxMarks: "39", gradeMinMarks: "30" }
​
6: Object { gradeName: "A++", gradeMaxMarks: "100", gradeMinMarks: "90" }
​
length: 7
```

I have above object in JavaScript, it is not sorting properly. How can I resolve this?

Comment: looks like 0, then 1, then 2 ... all the waay to 6 (hard to read though) ... what order were you expecting?

Comment: I am sorting with gradeMaxMarks.

Comment: By which value you want to sort this array of objects?

Comment: no you aren't ... you have an array that is in the order you wrote it ... I see no attempt at sorting

Comment: What is your current code to sort it?

Comment: I want to sort by gradeMaxMarks value. All other grades except A++ are sorted correctly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects Possible dupe. Alternative https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212737/sorted-a-javascript-array-of-objects-by-an-object-property

Comment: yes, but you're not showing your sorting **code** - how can we help you fix that if you don't show it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Javascript's [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method to sort array in **Descending Order** [100, 80, 60, 40, ....] (Your requirement) like below:

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.gradeMaxMarks - a.gradeMaxMarks;
});
```

If you want to sort array in **Ascending Order** [10, 20, 40, 45, 60, ....] then do it like this:

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.gradeMaxMarks - b.gradeMaxMarks;
});
```

Below is working code snippet:

```js
var array = [{gradeName:"A+",gradeMaxMarks:"89",gradeMinMarks:"80"},{gradeName:"A",gradeMaxMarks:"79",gradeMinMarks:"70"},{gradeName:"B+",gradeMaxMarks:"69",gradeMinMarks:"60"},{gradeName:"B",gradeMaxMarks:"59",gradeMinMarks:"55"},{gradeName:"C",gradeMaxMarks:"49",gradeMinMarks:"40"},{gradeName:"D",gradeMaxMarks:"39",gradeMinMarks:"30"},{gradeName:"A++",gradeMaxMarks:"100",gradeMinMarks:"90"}];

array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.gradeMaxMarks - a.gradeMaxMarks;
});

console.log(array)
```

Comment: This one is not working for my data. Actually i have my data stored in local storage. The value 100 for A++ is fixed.

Comment: @Sharathkumar what do you mean?

Comment: @Sharathkumar click on **Run code snippet** the blue Button to see the output

Comment: @Sharathkumar Edit your question to clarify it please.

Comment: In A++ gradeMaxMarks is 100. All other marks will have only 2 digits only. While sorting it will consider 100 as 10, I mean only first 2 digits it is considering

Comment: @Sharathkumar above code is not number of digits specific so it will work properly.

Comment: @VicJordan It is saying 'Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.'

Comment: @Sharathkumar got it

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [{
    gradeName: "A+",
    gradeMaxMarks: "89",
    gradeMinMarks: "80"
  },
  {
    gradeName: "A",
    gradeMaxMarks: "79",
    gradeMinMarks: "70"
  },
  {
    gradeName: "B+",
    gradeMaxMarks: "69",
    gradeMinMarks: "60"
  },
  {
    gradeName: "B",
    gradeMaxMarks: "59",
    gradeMinMarks: "55"
  },
  {
    gradeName: "C",
    gradeMaxMarks: "49",
    gradeMinMarks: "40"
  },
  {
    gradeName: "D",
    gradeMaxMarks: "39",
    gradeMinMarks: "30"
  },
  {
    gradeName: "A++",
    gradeMaxMarks: "100",
    gradeMinMarks: "90"
  }
]

arr.sort((a,b) => Number(b.gradeMaxMarks)-Number(a.gradeMaxMarks))
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: In A++ gradeMaxMarks is 100. All other marks will have only 2 digits only. While sorting it will consider 100 as 10, I mean only first 2 digits it is considering

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot the `sort` part of the script.

```js
const input = [{
    gradeName: "A+",
    gradeMaxMarks: "89",
    gradeMinMarks: "80"
  },
  {
    gradeName: "A",
    gradeMaxMarks: "79",
    gradeMinMarks: "70"
  },
  {
    gradeName: "B+",
    gradeMaxMarks: "69",
    gradeMinMarks: "60"
  },
  {
    gradeName: "B",
    gradeMaxMarks: "59",
    gradeMinMarks: "55"
  },
  {
    gradeName: "C",
    gradeMaxMarks: "49",
    gradeMinMarks: "40"
  },
  {
    gradeName: "D",
    gradeMaxMarks: "39",
    gradeMinMarks: "30"
  },
  {
    gradeName: "A++",
    gradeMaxMarks: "100",
    gradeMinMarks: "90"
  }
];

input.sort((a, b) => b.gradeMaxMarks - a.gradeMaxMarks);
console.log(input);
```

Comment: In A++ gradeMaxMarks is 100. All other marks will have only 2 digits only. While sorting it will consider 100 as 10, I mean only first 2 digits it is considering